# How can I see what is bitcoin tx for pending Lighting channel (lnd)

Tags: lightning-network-daemon

When I open a new Lightning channel from lncli I get the blockchain tx hash back.
But afterwards how can I find this hash later on, if the channel is still pending state?

lncli pendingchannels does not show any tx data and lncli listchaintxns does not show unconfirmed bitcoin tx.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The output of `lncli pendingchannels` gives you as much as you need:

```
"pending_open_channels": [
{
        "channel": {
            "remote_node_pub": <pubkey>,
            "channel_point": <txid:output_index>,
            "capacity": ,
            "local_balance": ,
            "remote_balance": 
        },
        "confirmation_height": ,
        "commit_fee": ,
        "commit_weight": ,
        "fee_per_kw": 
}]
```

The `channel_point` will give you the txid, that you can later lookup at a bitcoin testnet explorer, or directly with `btcctl --testnet gettransaction txid`